# Edit(update, delete) one of headers in karate

Tags: karate

I have this header which is in a `.js` file and I am reading this header using

```
* configure headers = read('classpath:services/Headers/distheader.js')
```

**Question #1**

- How can I edit one of the headers in this file at run-time using my scenario data?
  I tried setting `* header 'xyz' = 'value'` but it doesn't edit it.

**Question #2**

- If I want to delete one of the headers, how is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So 90% of your scenarios are "happy path", and you have a `headers` JS configured.

Now you need some scenarios to have more (or less headers). One option is to hard-code the headers for those scenarios, note that you can do `* configure headers = null` to disable the "auto" headers. Then use the `header` (or `headers`) keyword and build headers manually.

Another option is that you can invoke the headers function and get a JSON - and then mutate (add / remove keys) before setting headers *manually*. For example:

```
# you can disable headers if needed
* configure headers = null

# headers.feature is: function(){ return { a: 1, b: 2 } }
* def fun = read('headers.feature')
* def temp = fun()
* remove temp.a
* set temp.c = 3

Given url 'https://httpbin.org'
And path 'anything'
And headers temp
When method get
Then status 200
```

So the advantage above is in case your headers routine is complex, you can re-use it - but still have fine-grained control.

For more ideas, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76672675/143475