# Karate global function is undefined exception

Tags: karate

Unable to call `appendGlobalHeaders` from scenario, getting `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "appendGlobalHeaders" is not defined`

In `karate-config.js`:

```js
karate.configure('headers', {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <your-token>'
});

function appendGlobalHeaders(headers) {
  var globalHeaders = karate.get('headers');
  return karate.append(headers, globalHeaders);
}
```

In Karate test file:

```
Feature: Append Global Headers to Request Headers

  Scenario: Make an API request with appended headers
    Given url 'https://api.example.com/users'
    * def requestHeaders = appendGlobalHeaders({ 'X-Custom-Header': 'Custom-Value' })
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not implemented `karate-config.js` correctly or understood Karate variables. I also think you should try a different approach.

Why don't you try this in `karate-config.js` (this is the complete code):

```
function fn() {
  var headersFn = function() {
    var headers = { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <my-token>',
      'Extra-Header': karate.get('myVariable')
    };
    return headers;
  };
  karate.configure('headers', headersFn);
}
```

And in your feature you can do this:

```
* def myVariable = 'foo'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method get
```

Try it and see how it works.

And one good thing is that if a value is `null`, Karate won't set that header. You can use that to your dynamic advantage. Note that you can conditionally add headers with if-then conditions as explained in the documentation.

Maybe instead of all this complexity, you may choose to just go with a simple approach where each `Scenario` sets headers using the `header` or `headers` keyword and you don't use `configure` at all. That's perfectly fine and up to you.

Another approach you could try is something like this:

```
* headers genHeaders('X-Custom-Header', 'Custom-Value')
```

So all you need to do is define a function in scope called `genHeaders` that returns a JSON.